# Show standard devation using geom_smooth and ggplot

Tags: r, statistics, ggplot2

We have some data which represents many model runs under different scenarios. For a single scenario, we'd like to display the smoothed mean, with the filled areas representing standard deviation at a particular point in time, rather than the quality of the fit of smooting.

For example:

```
d <- as.data.frame(rbind(cbind(1:20, 1:20, 1),
                          cbind(1:20, -1:-20, 2)))
names(d)<-c("Time","Value","Run")

ggplot(d, aes(x=Time, y=Value)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=Run)) +
  geom_smooth()
```

This produces a graph with two runs represented, and a smoothed mean, but even though the SD between the runs is increasing, the smoother's bars stay the same size. I'd like to make the surrounds of the smoother represent standard deviation at a given timestep.

Is there a non-labour intensive way of doing this, given many different runs and output variables?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

hi i'm not sure if I correctly understand what you want, but for example,

```
d <- data.frame(Time=rep(1:20, 4), 
                Value=rnorm(80, rep(1:20, 4)+rep(1:4*2, each=20)),
                Run=gl(4,20))

mean_se <- function(x, mult = 1) {  
  x <- na.omit(x)
  se <- mult * sqrt(var(x) / length(x))
  mean <- mean(x)
  data.frame(y = mean, ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean + se)
}

ggplot( d, aes(x=Time,y=Value) ) + geom_line( aes(group=Run) ) + 
  geom_smooth(se=FALSE) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_se, geom="ribbon", alpha=0.25)
```

note that mean_se is going to appear in the next version of ggplot2.

Comment: It's been a while since this post, @kohske, how would you do this with the current version of ggplot2? Do you just run the function `stat_summary(fun.data=mean_se, geom="ribbon", alpha=0.25)` without defining the function?

Comment: Indeed @torenunez it's now bundled and you could just use it.

Comment: This answer seems to confuse standard deviation with standard error? but you can also just use the mean_sd function instead, just as shown.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer just works if measurements are aligned/discretized on x. In case of continuous data you could use a rolling window and add a custom ribbon

```
iris %>%
    ## apply same grouping as for plot
    group_by(Species) %>%
    ## Important sort along x!
    arrange(Petal.Length) %>%
    ## calculate rolling mean and sd
    mutate(rolling_sd=rollapply(Petal.Width, width=10, sd,  fill=NA), rolling_mean=rollmean(Petal.Width, k=10, fill=NA)) %>%  # table_browser()
    ## build the plot
    ggplot(aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, color = Species)) +
    # optionally we could rather plot the rolling mean instead of the geom_smooth loess fit
    # geom_line(aes(y=rolling_mean), color="black") +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=rolling_mean-rolling_sd/2, ymax=rolling_mean+rolling_sd/2), fill="lightgray", color="lightgray", alpha=.8) +
    geom_point(size = 1, alpha = .7) +
    geom_smooth(se=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: in this case, why do the ribbons not go to the end?

Comment: @JB1 Because it's calculated with rollapply, which needs some data points (here set to 10) to work out the ribbon boundaries.

Comment: ahh thats good to know! thanks