# Is it possible to show standard deviation using geom_smooth in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, dplyr

im currently using the geom_smooth function to plot bacterial growth data.

I'm wondering if its possible to display the standard deviation as opposed to the confidence interval calculated by the standard error (as i think is the standard for this function)

Example:

```
p1<-mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=mpg,cyl)) +
  geom_smooth( size=2, span=1,color="tomato",fill="tomato")
```

[image]

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to display the running standard deviation using geom_smooth?
2. If not, is there another way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show standard devation using geom\_smooth and ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205428/show-standard-devation-using-geom-smooth-and-ggplot)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to do this nowadays directly inside `geom_smooth` because we can work out the standard deviation from the calculated standard error inside `after_stat`

```r
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(mpg, cyl)) +
  geom_smooth(size = 2, span = 1, color = "tomato", fill = "tomato",
              aes(ymax = after_stat(y + se * sqrt(length(y))),
                  ymin = after_stat(y - se * sqrt(length(y)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Allan, it works great and i truly appreciate it! In my specific case, the data has two axis and two sets of y-axis data. Is it possible to plot the rolling SD using this method for two lines on the same plot?

Comment: @Salt_Industry yes, just repeat the geom_smooth code but add `y = second_variable` inside the `aes` part of the call